# "Shuttling between the anal and genital zones of development." Huh?

Tags: terminology

Here's a quote from *Lolita*:

> "Dolly Haze," she said, "is a lovely child, but the onset of sexual
>   maturing seems to give her trouble."
>
> I bowed slightly. What else could I do?
>
> "**She is still shuttling**," said Miss Pratt, showing how with her
>   liver-spotted hands, "**between the anal and genital zones of
>   development**. Basically she is a lovely..."
>
> "I beg your pardon," I said, "what zones?"
>
> "That's the old-fashioned European in you!" cried Pratt delivering a
>   slight tap on my wrist watch and suddenly disclosing her dentures.
>   "All I mean is that biologic drives--do you smoke?--are not fused in
>   Dolly, do not fall so to speak into a--into a rounded pattern."
>
> Her hands held for a moment an invisible melon.

What the hell does it mean? Is it some kind of late 1940's psychobabble, or a disdainful parody of same, or what?

Comment: It's Freud. Same use of *anal* as in "anal-retentive" to refer to a personality type.

Comment: @sumelic: Thank you. I still don't get it, though.

Comment: [anal stage](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anal_stage), [genital stage](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genital_stage). The anal stage is supposedly an immature stage in the development of an individual's sexuality; the genital stage is the final, mature stage.

Comment: She's saying that Dolly is becoming a young woman but hasn't shown the usual interest in boys that she should (no wonder with Humbert lurking in the background all the time). It's also trying to parody psychobabble, which was gaining in popularity during the time, especially for teen development.  If you haven't listened to Jeremy Irons' reading of Lolita, you should do so, Ricky...I would also recommend seeing the movie with Irons...it really brings to life the disturbing aspects of this novel.

Comment: @michael_timofeev: So what is "the anal zone of development"? ... I daresay I'm somewhat better equipped to understand literature than some pretentious actor. I've seen the movie. It's boring as hell. As is the other one. The novel is fast-paced and sparkling; the movies are slow, dull, and "moody," grossly miscast, platitudinous, and completely void of any kind of talent, including cinematographic talent.

Comment: We shall have to agree to disagree about your soapboxing, but I'm more of a Jungian, so for me, anything Freud smacks of BS.  (Jeremy Irons...pretentious?)

Comment: @michael_timofeev: Jeremy Irons, pretentious, confirmed. All psychobabble sounds like bullshit to me. I still want an answer, though. What did Freud, or Jung, mean by "the anal zone of development"?

Comment: Sumelic gave you an answer...check the links...come on bro, you don't need all the handholding.  If I remember, Nabakov makes several references to pop psychology in the book, this being one of them, and the other references weren't very glamorizing of the emerging field.  Also, Humbert is an unreliable narrator, so everything has to be filtered through his POV...who knows what he really heard...always keep this in mind when reading Lolita.

Comment: @michael_timofeev: "filtered": Yes, which is why I specifically asked whether it was a parody of something.

Comment: It's immaterial what we think of Freud. Nabokov painted in Miss Pratt's priggish character a Freudian pedantry, which was a popular fashion at that time, and that is the key to understanding what the text conveys. Arguing against that because you prefer Jung is like arguing men never walked on the moon because you don't like Michael Jackson's dancing.

Comment: Don't blame Kubrick for the first movie. I guarantee you it would have been great had it been up to him. The censors gave the poor guy absolute hell: http://www.moviefone.com/2012/06/11/lolita-stanley-kubrick-vladimir-nabokov/

Comment: A slightly offtopic question by a new user here... Some of these comments seem to make a great answer, yet they are posted as a comment and not an answer. Would anyone indulge a newbie on the block and explain why an answer would not be offered as such? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Terah: I posted comments because it wasn't clear to me what type of answer Ricky wanted. As you can see by his responses, the links I provided did not fully answer Ricky's question.

Comment: @terah It happens a lot (in blatant conflict with the site rules). Generally it's people being too lazy to bother formatting and linking the way a good answer should. Or maybe they fear their peers having a "downvote option". In any case I'm sure that some of Freud's ego babble is totally appropriate.

Answer (score 5):

[It's Freud. He classified those as 2 of 5 steps in psychological development.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psychosexual_development)
[It's similar to the use of anal as in "anal-retentive" to refer to a personality type.](http://define:%22anal%20retentive%22)

ps. If Freud ain't your style then Nabokov probably isn't either... be prepared

pps. "Answers! Not comments!"